# Pyspark: repartition vs partitionBy

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I'm working through these two concepts right now and would like some clarity.  From working through the command line, I've been trying to identify the differences and when a developer would use repartition vs partitionBy.

Here is some sample code:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('b', 3), ('c',1), ('ef',5)])
rdd1 = rdd.repartition(4)
rdd2 = rdd.partitionBy(4)

rdd1.glom().collect()
[[('b', 1), ('ef', 5)], [], [], [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('c', 1)]]

rdd2.glom().collect()
[[('a', 1), ('a', 2)], [], [('c', 1)], [('b', 1), ('b', 3), ('ef', 5)]]
```

I took a look at the implementation of both, and the only difference I've noticed for the most part is that partitionBy can take a partitioning function, or using the portable_hash by default.  So in partitionBy, all the same keys should be in the same partition.  In repartition, I would expect the values to be distributed more evenly over the partitions, but this isnt the case.

Given this, why would anyone ever use repartition?  I suppose the only time I could see it being used is if I'm not working with PairRDD, or I have large data skew?

Is there something that I'm missing, or could someone shed light from a different angle for me?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`repartition` already exists in RDDs, and does not handle partitioning by key (or by any other criterion except Ordering). Now PairRDDs add the notion of keys and subsequently add another method that allows to partition by that key.

So yes, if your data is keyed, you should absolutely partition by that key, which in many cases is the point of using a PairRDD in the first place (for joins, reduceByKey, and so on).

Comment: What is the reason that repartition doesn't distribute the elements evenly ish across the partitions?  Could this be a case where I don't have enough data, and we're experiencing small sample size issue?

Comment: Good question, I'm seeing an even distribution when trying it out (in Scala).

Comment: @JoeWiden Nothing else than a simple probability. `repartition` is actually using pair RDD internally by adding random key to the existing values so it doesn't provide strong guarantees about about the output data distribution. BTW You should probably accept the answer.

Comment: @MariusSoutier Actually __any__ repartitioning in Spark is handled using pair RDDs. If needed Spark just adds dummy keys or dummy values to make it work.

Answer (score 22):

`repartition()` is used for specifying the number of partitions considering the number of cores and the amount of data you have.

`partitionBy()` is used for making shuffling functions more efficient, such as `reduceByKey()`, `join()`, `cogroup()` etc.. It is only beneficial in cases where a RDD is used for multiple times, so it is usually followed by `persist()`.

Differences between the two in action:

```
pairs = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 5, 6, 7, 7, 5, 5, 6, 4]).map(lambda x: (x, x))

pairs.partitionBy(3).glom().collect()
[[(3, 3), (6, 6), (6, 6)],
 [(1, 1), (4, 4), (4, 4), (1, 1), (7, 7), (7, 7), (4, 4)],
 [(2, 2), (2, 2), (5, 5), (5, 5), (5, 5)]]

pairs.repartition(3).glom().collect()
[[(4, 4), (2, 2), (6, 6), (7, 7), (5, 5), (5, 5)],
 [(1, 1), (4, 4), (6, 6), (4, 4)],
 [(2, 2), (3, 3), (1, 1), (5, 5), (7, 7)]]
```