# Spark RDD partition by key in exclusive way

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I would like to partition an RDD by key and have that each parition contains only values of a single key. For example, if I have 100 different values of the key and I `repartition(102)`, the RDD should have 2 empty partitions and 100 partitions containing each one a single key value.

I tried with `groupByKey(k).repartition(102)` but this does not guarantee the exclusivity of a key in each partition, since I see some partitions containing more values of a single key and more than 2 empty.

Is there a way in the standard API to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

to use partitionBy() RDD must consist of tuple (pair) objects. Lets see an example below:

Suppose I have an Input file with following data:

```
OrderId|OrderItem|OrderDate|OrderPrice|ItemQuantity
1|Gas|2018-01-17|1895|1
1|Air Conditioners|2018-01-28|19000|3
1|Television|2018-01-11|45000|2
2|Gas|2018-01-17|1895|1
2|Air Conditioners|2017-01-28|19000|3
2|Gas|2016-01-17|2300|1
1|Bottle|2018-03-24|45|10
1|Cooking oil|2018-04-22|100|3
3|Inverter|2015-11-02|29000|1
3|Gas|2014-01-09|2300|1
3|Television|2018-01-17|45000|2
4|Gas|2018-01-17|2300|1
4|Television$$|2018-01-17|45000|2
5|Medicine|2016-03-14|23.50|8
5|Cough Syrup|2016-01-28|190|1
5|Ice Cream|2014-09-23|300|7
5|Pasta|2015-06-30|65|2

PATH_TO_FILE="file:///u/vikrant/OrderInputFile"
```

reading file into RDD and skip header

```
RDD = sc.textFile(PATH_TO_FILE)
header=RDD.first();
newRDD = RDD.filter(lambda x:x != header)
```

now Lets re-partition RDD into '5' partitions

```
partitionRDD = newRDD.repartition(5)
```

lets have a look how data is being distributed in these '5' partitions

```
print("Partitions structure: {}".format(partitionRDD.glom().collect()))
```

here you can see that data is written into two partitions  and, three of them are empty and also it's not being distributed uniformly.

```
Partitions structure: [[], 
[u'1|Gas|2018-01-17|1895|1', u'1|Air Conditioners|2018-01-28|19000|3', u'1|Television|2018-01-11|45000|2', u'2|Gas|2018-01-17|1895|1', u'2|Air Conditioners|2017-01-28|19000|3', u'2|Gas|2016-01-17|2300|1', u'1|Bottle|2018-03-24|45|10', u'1|Cooking oil|2018-04-22|100|3', u'3|Inverter|2015-11-02|29000|1', u'3|Gas|2014-01-09|2300|1'], 
[u'3|Television|2018-01-17|45000|2', u'4|Gas|2018-01-17|2300|1', u'4|Television$$|2018-01-17|45000|2', u'5|Medicine|2016-03-14|23.50|8', u'5|Cough Syrup|2016-01-28|190|1', u'5|Ice Cream|2014-09-23|300|7', u'5|Pasta|2015-06-30|65|2'], 
[], []]
```

We need create a pair RDD in order have the RDD data distributed uniformly across the number of partitions.
Lets create a pair RDD and break it into key value pair.

```
pairRDD = newRDD.map(lambda x :(x[0],x[1:]))
```

now lets re partition this rdd into '5' partition and distribute the data uniformly into the partitions using key at [0]th position.

```
newpairRDD = pairRDD.partitionBy(5,lambda k: int(k[0]))
```

now we can see that data is being distributed uniformly according to the matching key value pairs.

```
print("Partitions structure: {}".format(newpairRDD.glom().collect()))
Partitions structure: [
[(u'5', u'|Medicine|2016-03-14|23.50|8'), 
(u'5', u'|Cough Syrup|2016-01-28|190|1'), 
(u'5', u'|Ice Cream|2014-09-23|300|7'), 
(u'5', u'|Pasta|2015-06-30|65|2')],

[(u'1', u'|Gas|2018-01-17|1895|1'), 
(u'1', u'|Air Conditioners|2018-01-28|19000|3'), 
(u'1', u'|Television|2018-01-11|45000|2'), 
(u'1', u'|Bottle|2018-03-24|45|10'), 
(u'1', u'|Cooking oil|2018-04-22|100|3')], 

[(u'2', u'|Gas|2018-01-17|1895|1'), 
(u'2', u'|Air Conditioners|2017-01-28|19000|3'), 
(u'2', u'|Gas|2016-01-17|2300|1')], 

[(u'3', u'|Inverter|2015-11-02|29000|1'), 
(u'3', u'|Gas|2014-01-09|2300|1'), 
(u'3', u'|Television|2018-01-17|45000|2')], 

[(u'4', u'|Gas|2018-01-17|2300|1'), 
(u'4', u'|Television$$|2018-01-17|45000|2')]
]
```

below you can verify the number of records in each partitions.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc
from pyspark.sql.functions import spark_partition_id

partitionSizes = newpairRDD.glom().map(len).collect();

[4, 5, 3, 3, 2]
```

Please note that when you create a pair RDD of key value pair, your key should be of type int else you will get an error.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Vikrant! What's the difference between `partitionBy()` and `repartition()`? Could you not use them interchangably? Instead of using `partitionBy()` in `newpairRDD = pairRDD.partitionBy(5,lambda k: int(k[0]))` could you have not used `repartition()` here? Can you dwell a bit on the difference between the two?

Comment: @cph_sto.. yes, you can. you may get more information in the link mentioned below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416357/spark-sql-difference-between-df-repartition-and-dataframewriter-partitionby & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33831561/pyspark-repartition-vs-partitionby

Comment: Vikrant, I have read many of your question/answers over the last few months and they have been very helpful. Allow me, though belatedly to uptick them.

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416357/spark-sql-difference-between-df-repartition-and-dataframewriter-partitionby) very well address the original question that I had in my mind. Many thanks for refering me to those links.

Comment: @cph_sto.. Thanks for such a inspiring words. ☺️

Comment: @cph_sto.. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

For an RDD, have you tried using [partitionBy](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) to partition the RDD by key, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32544307/how-to-partition-by-key-in-spark)?  You can specify the number of partitions to be the number of keys to get rid of the empty partitions if desired.

In the Dataset API, you can use [repartition](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) with a `Column` as an argument to partition by the values in that column (although note that this uses the value of `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` as the number of partitions, so you'll get a lot more empty partitions).