# Why the Spark's repartition didn't balance data into partitions?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize(range(10), 2)
>>> rdd.glom().collect()
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
>>> rdd.repartition(3).glom().collect()
[[], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
>>>
```

The first partition is empty? Why? I really appreciate you telling me the reasons.

Comment: Are you worried about first partition being empty or a partition being empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because Spark doesn't shuffle individual elements but rather blocks of data - [with minimum batch size equal to 10](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8171b156ebf25a582318c71222716b5c52c8bbb3/python/pyspark/rdd.py#L2107).

So if you have less elements than that per partition, Spark won't separate content of partitions.

Answer (score 1):

This can be explained by just taking a look at how the repartition function works.
The reason for this is that calling `df.repartition(COL, numPartitions=k)` will create a dataframe with `k` partitions using a hash-based partitioned. Pyspark will go through every row and apply the following [function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html) to determine where the element in the current row will end :

```
partition_the_row_belongs_to = hash(COL) % k
```

The `k` in this case is used for mapping the rows into a space consisting of k partitions. As you can see, there are times where hash functions collides. Sometimes some partitions will be empty whist others have too many elements. This can be because of hash map conclusions, or because of the hash function. Either way the reason for what you are seeing is that repartition created 3 partitions as you asked for, it doesn't promise you anything about balancing the partitions or having all partitions non-empty. If you want to have more control on how the resulting partitions look like, look at [partitionby](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html).

See also: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33831561/5695374) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40416357/5695374).

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth while noting that as Spark is all about running at scale, this is an unlikely scenario to worry about. The closest you can get is skewed data. range will give different initial partitioning than repartition which will use hashing. Also the comment on batch size is valid, but less relevant in practice.